# PSR: should I add basic classes to the namespace section?

Tags: php, coding-style, psr-0

Some people add basic classes like Exception, Throwable, DateTime etc to the namespace section like this:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar;

use DateTime;
use Throwable;

Class MyClass{

    public function getDate()
    {
        try {
            new DateTime('Bizarre value');
        } catch (Throwable $exception) {
            //error handling
        }
    }
}

(new MyClass())->getDate();
```

But other people just add a slash in front of those basic classes:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar;

Class MyClass{

    public function getDate()
    {
        try {
            new \DateTime('Bizarre value');
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            //error handling
        }
    }
}

(new MyClass())->getDate();
```

What is the "canonical" one according to PSR?

Comment: The current coding style standard recommendation would be [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) and it doesn't seem to mention that so I'd dare say there's no FIG canon. If you ask for my opinion (why would you?), creating an alias to save one char is a peculiar approach.